# How to help cure a disc protrusion

Tags: diet, exercise, back, inflammation

Besides anti-inflammatory medicines and resting, I was wondering what are the best practices to help correct a bulging disc or disc protrusion when walking, sitting, sleeping.

I heard about reinforcing the abdominal area and some other exercises.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are talking about trying to help a possible disc pathology in your lower back region because you referenced the abdominal area. For lower back discs most of the time it is due to a flexion intolerance, in my opinion, and from the work of Prof Stuart McGill & Dr Craig Liebenson which you can see here http://chirocentre.co.uk/lower-back-bent-over-forward-flexion-intolerant-spine/

Lower back pain from a lumbar disc source of pain tends to get worse from poor controlled lumbar spine flexion. That's why the McKenzie exercises are recommended physical therapists and chiropractors. Abdominal hollowing is one train of thought however, I follow the thinking of the work coming out of the Prague School of Rehabilitation method more which recommends using abdominal breathing instead. So pushing your stomach out when you breath in and pulling it in when you breath out. They also have other exercises or postures they recommended to help out. I made a massive Youtube playlist for people to watch if they want https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlQpsUduPwnH4Umm3fKrBG3V_ZrtlXU--